# Partial Chain validation failure of received WCF server certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl, x509certificate

We are integrating with a service that uses client certificates to verify the https connection between ourselves and a vendor server. We generated a CSR and the vendor supplied back to us a p7b file with 2 intermediate certificates and a trusted root certificate. We then created a pfx binary with the private key from the CSR (we can match the certificates and keys, so we know they are correct from that point-of-view).

We use Vault to store our mutual authentication certificates so the pfx is *not* installed onto the Windows Server 2012r2.

In our client code we do the following:

```cs
var myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

var client = new ServiceClient(myBinding, new EndpointAddress("https://example.org"));
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "****");
client.create(new model());
```

With the above setup we have the following affects:

- Windows 10 Development Machine - TLS connection successfully made
- Windows Server 2012r2 - TLS connection fails

We then added a validation callback:

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateServerCertificate;

private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
   // ...
}
```

At this point the `sslPolicyErrors` is `System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors`.

If we attempt to build our own SSL chain:

```cs
using (var chain = new X509Chain())
{
  var flag = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;
  chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
  chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = flag;

  var primaryCert = new X509Certificate2(certificate);

  var n = chain.Build(primaryCert);
  Console.WriteLine($"Flag: {flag} - {string.Join(",", chain.ChainStatus.Select(x => $"{x.StatusInformation.Trim()} ({x.Status})"))}");

  return n;
}
```

We get the print - `Flag: NoFlag - A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority. (PartialChain)`

So we changed the flag to `X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority`.

Doing this caused the certificate chain to be correctly validated.

The questions we have are:

1. We have different effects happening on different machines, so our conclusion is that Win 10 is not being as strict with its checking. Is there any reason why Server 2012r2 would reject the chain?
2. Are there any security issues if we use the verification flag `X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority`?
3. Can we set this flag in the setup of the client, or does it have to be part of the validation callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so our conclusion is that Win 10 is not being as strict with its checking

it is incorrect. Windows Client and Windows Server OS share same cryptographic code (CAPI2) and configuration.

> Are there any security issues if we use the verification flag `X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority?`

yes, this flag opens doors for [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks.

> Can we set this flag in the setup of the client, or does it have to be part of the validation callback?

what you really need is to resolve the issue. The error indicates that server certificate was not issued by a trusted CA. This CA (the issuer of server TLS certificate) is trusted by development machine, because developer trusts this CA (administrator has installed development CA certificate in trusted root store).

If you have received CA certificates from vendor, they must be installed on Windows Server 2012 box as well. And this will automatically solve the issue.

Comment: Dev and Server machines run the same group policies so they both have the same root certs. We can't find any differences between them. Is there a way to find the cert that could be causing the issue?

Comment: Root certificate (from vendor) was most likely installed manually on Windows 10 box. Run `cermgr.msc` on both machines and compare certificates in Trusted Root CAs store.

Comment: Our Server doesn't appear to have that util - we have used `mmc` though to compare. The issuer comes from DigiCert - server and dev have all the same DigiCert certificates in the Trusted Root CA store.

Comment: sorry, there is a typo. Correct is `certmgr.msc`. I would double-check if certificate received from TLS handshake is the expected one (from DigiCert). I suspect, either, a misconfiguration on your end or wrong certificate received from server.

Comment: On dev machine, the chain is 3 deep with the last one is from `DigiCert Global Root CA`. Searching for the serial number shows the same 2 certificates on dev and server. The other 2 in the chain don't appear in either dev/server boxes. From the Thumbprint, dev/server are receiving the same cert from the server.

Comment: Then one or more of DigiCert intermediate CA certificates is missing from Windows Server 2012 box. Roots are ok. You can find them in `Intermediate CAs` certificate store on Windows 10 box. You will certainly find a difference.

Comment: Bingo - found the `Intermediate CA` for DigiCert that was missing. It was installed under `Current User` not `Local Machine` so we kept searching in the wrong place. Installing the DigiCert cert onto the server resolved the problem. Thanks for the help.